# Postconditions and TDD

Tags: tdd, code-contracts

One colleague in my team says that some methods should have both preconditions & postconditions. But the point is about code coverage, those conditions were not being called (not tested) until an invalid implementation implemented (just used in unit test). Lets take below example.

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    int Calculate(int x, int y);
}


public int GetSummary(int x, int y)
{
    // preconditions

    var result = calculator.Calculate(x, y);

    // postconditions

    if (result < 0)
    {
        **throw new Exception("...");**
    }

    return result;
}
```

Two options for us:

1/ Remove test implementations + postconditions

2/ Keep both test implementations + postconditions

Can you give some advice please?

Answer (score 4):

Keep pre- and post-conditions.

You'll need at least four tests here: combinations of (pre, post) x (pass, fail).  Your failing post-condition test will pass if the expected exception is thrown.

This is easy to do in JUnit with its `@Test(expected = Exception.class)` annotation.

Be careful with colleagues that make blanket statements like "X must always be true."  Dogma in all its forms should be avoided.  Understand the reasons for doing things and do them when they make sense.

Comment: Didn't you mean, "Always avoid dogma." ?   ;-)

Comment: Found out that there was an issue with our tests, it's a matter of mocking referenced service (in this example is ICalculator). Also it can be mocked to returns bad results to violate postconditions and removed the "invalid implementation implemented (just used in unit test)".

Comment: If the test is intended for the service class, I don't see any value in mocking it.  You only mock dependencies, not the class that you're writing the test for.

Answer (score 1):

These conditions should be seen from design view. They **ensure** the calculator should be working fine, returning result in a range of expected values.

You should see the MS code [contracts project](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) to take a document there.